# Why is linux kernel not using my driver

Tags: module, load, kernel, driver

I have tried to write a simple linux char device driver using this tutorial: http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2007/04/writing-a-linux-kernel-driver-for-an-unknown-usb-device/

I am using slightly newer device and slightly newer kernel. So I used their code changing product and vendor id and I am just trying to make kernel call probe function when device is attached which I failed to do looking at my /var/log/messages. Driver loads successfully:

```
Sep  5 18:32:43 manticore kernel: [10673.664884] usbcore: deregistering interface driver missile_launcher
Sep  5 18:32:43 manticore kernel: [10673.664908] [info]  usb_ml_exit(661): module deregistered
Sep  5 18:32:43 manticore kernel: [10673.666314] usbcore: registered new interface driver missile_launcher
Sep  5 18:32:43 manticore kernel: [10673.666317] [info]  usb_ml_init(651): driver registered successfully
```

But when device is attached the driver is not used:

```
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295688] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2123, idProduct=1010
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295689] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295691] usb 3-1.1: Product: USB Missile Launcher
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295693] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: Syntek
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295789] usb 3-1.1: usb_probe_device
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295791] usb 3-1.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295797] usb 3-1.1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.295855] usb 3-1.1: Successful Endpoint Configure command
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.296132] usb 3-1.1: adding 3-1.1:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.296173] usbhid 3-1.1:1.0: usb_probe_interface
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.296174] usbhid 3-1.1:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.298577] usbhid 3-1.1:1.0: looking for a minor, starting at 96
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.298697] generic-usb 0003:2123:1010.0008: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Syntek USB Missile Launcher] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1/input0
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.298712] drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '016'
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.298754] hub 3-1:1.0: port 2, status 0101, change 0000, 12 Mb/s
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.310627] hub 3-1:1.0: port 2 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.372509] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.418456] usb 3-1.2: skipped 1 descriptor after configuration
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.418460] usb 3-1.2: skipped 6 descriptors after interface
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.418462] usb 3-1.2: skipped 1 descriptor after endpoint
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.418463] usb 3-1.2: skipped 9 descriptors after interface
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.419100] usb 3-1.2: default language 0x0409
Sep  5 17:58:12 manticore kernel: [ 8607.421607] usb 3-1.2: udev 17, busnum 3, minor = 272
```

The code I have that is responsible for making this association is:

```
#define ML_VENDOR_ID    0x2123
#define ML_PRODUCT_ID   0x1010


static struct usb_device_id ml_table [] = {
        { USB_DEVICE(ML_VENDOR_ID, ML_PRODUCT_ID) },
        { }
};

static struct usb_driver ml_driver = {
        .name = "missile_launcher",
        .id_table = ml_table,
        .probe = ml_probe,
        .disconnect = ml_disconnect,
};
```

My kernel version is 3.3.8

Any ideas what might be wrong?

BTW. I am completely new at this so it is very likely that I skipped some relevant information please ask me if something more is needed.